# TicTacToe: method to check diagonal win

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am new to Java and I am trying to build a simple TicTacToe-game. I built the method checkforWin to check the winner for the different combinations on the board and it apparently seems that it works but it appears to be very cumbersome and I am not sure it is to be considered "good coding". This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TicTacToeNeu {
    static public char playerPiece = 'X';
    static public char computerPiece = 'O'; 
    static char[] [] board = {{'_','|','_','|','_'},
            {'_', '|', '_','|','_'},
            {' ','|',' ','|',' '}};
    static boolean gameOver = false;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner imputScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Would you like to start?"); // "Would you like to start (Yes/No)"               
        String firstImput = imputScanner.nextLine(); // input user      
        boolean playersTurn = start(firstImput);
        if (!playersTurn) { //it's the computers turn first
            int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 4); //random number between 0 and 3
            switch (rand) {
            case 0:
                board[0][0] = computerPiece;
                break;
            case 1:
                board[0][4] = computerPiece;
                break;
            case 2:
                board[2][0] = computerPiece;
                break;
            case 3:
                board[2][4] = computerPiece;
                break;
            }    
            playersTurn = true;
        }
        while(true) {
            if(playersTurn) {
                printBoard(board);
                System.out.println("Give a number from 1 to 9");
                int secondImput = imputScanner.nextInt();
                playerMove(board, secondImput);
                boolean playerWinner = checkforWin(board);
                if(playerWinner == true) {
                    gameOver = true;
                    System.out.println("You won!");
                }
            }
            else {
                computerMove(board);
                boolean computerWinner = checkforWin(board);
                if(computerWinner == true && gameOver == false) {
                    System.out.println("Computer won!");
                }
            }   
            playersTurn = !playersTurn;
        }       
    }
    public static boolean checkforWin(char [] [] board) {
        for(int r = 0; r < 3; r ++) {
            //check horizontal winner
            if(board[r][0] == 'X' && board[r][2] == 'X' && board[r][4] == 'X') {        
                return true;
            }
            else if(board[r][0] == 'O' && board[r][2] == 'O' && board[r][4] == 'O') {       
                return true;
            }
        }
        // check vertical winner    
        for(int c = 0; c <= 4; c += 2 ) {
            if(board[0][c] == 'X' && board[1][c] == 'X' && board[2][c] == 'X') {
                return true;
            }
            else if(board[0][c] == 'O' && board[1][c] == 'O' && board[2][c] == 'O') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        //check diagonal winner X (player)
        if(board[1][2]=='X') {
            for(int x = 0; x <= board.length; x ++){
                if((board[0][0] == 'X' && board[2][4]=='X')||(board[0][4]=='X'&&board[2][0]=='X')) {
                    return true;
                }   
            }
        }
        else if (board[1][2]=='O') {  //check diagonal winner O (computer)
            for(int x = 0; x <= board.length; x ++){
                if((board[0][0] == 'O' && board[2][4]=='O')||(board[0][4]=='O'&&board[2][0]=='O')) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //  public static boolean validateImputUser(String imputUser) {
    //      
    //      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //      imputUser = in.nextLine();
    //      while (imputUser.length() != 2) {
    //      return false;
    //      System.out.println("Geben Ihr Eingabe wieder");
    //      imputUser = in.nextLine();
    //  }
    //      return true;    
    //  }
    public static void computerMove(char [] [] board) {
        char character = 'O';   
        int position = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
        boolean result = validateMove(position, board); // controls open space on the board 
        while(!result) {
            position = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            result = validateMove(position, board);         
        }
        switch (position){
        case 1:
            board[0][0] = character;
            break;
        case 2:
            board[0][2] = character;
            break;
        case 3:
            board[0][4] = character;
            break;
        case 4:
            board[1][0] = character;
            break;
        case 5:
            board[1][2] = character;
            break;
        case 6:
            board[1][4] = character;
            break;
        case 7:
            board[2][0] = character;
            break;
        case 8:
            board[2][2] = character;
            break;
        case 9:
            board[2][4] = character;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    public static boolean validateMove(int position, char[][] board) {
        switch (position){
        case 1:
            if(board[0][0] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        case 2:
            if(board[0][2] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        case 3:
            if(board[0][4] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        case 4:
            if(board[1][0] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        case 5:
            if(board[1][2] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        case 6:
            if(board[1][4] == '_'){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        case 7:
            if(board[2][0] == ' '){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        case 8:
            if(board[2][2] == ' '){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        case 9:
            if(board[2][4] == ' '){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static void playerMove(char [] [] board, int position) {
        char character = 'X';       
        boolean result = validateMove(position, board);
        while(!result) {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            System.out.println("Give a number between 1 and 9");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            position = scan.nextInt();
            result = validateMove(position, board);
        }
        switch (position){
        case 1:
            board[0][0] = character;
            break;
        case 2:
            board[0][2] = character;
            break;
        case 3:
            board[0][4] = character;
            break;
        case 4:
            board[1][0] = character;
            break;
        case 5:
            board[1][2] = character;
            break;
        case 6:
            board[1][4] = character;
            break;
        case 7:
            board[2][0] = character;
            break;
        case 8:
            board[2][2] = character;
            break;
        case 9:
            board[2][4] = character;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    public static boolean start (String imput) {
        if(imput.equals("Yes")) {
            return true;
        }   
        return false;
    }
    public static void printBoard(char [] [] board) {   
        for(char [] row: board) {
            for(char column: row) { 
                System.out.print(column);   
            }
            System.out.println();   
        }
    }
}
```

The question would be if it would not be better to split the method checkforWin in two methods, one for the player and one for the computer. Morevover, I don't know if it is a good idea to use and if-else statement for checking the diagonal win on the board, starting two check the central position (board[1][2]). Every hint to improve this part of the code would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below method to check for diagonals.
Please note:
The primary diagonal positions are: `0,0` , `1,1` , `2,2`.
The secondary diagonal positions are: `0,2` , `1,1` , `2,0`.

```
    public static int checkforDiagonalWin(char [][] board)
    {
        // If `player` wins : return 1
        if (board[0][0] = 'X' && board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2])
            return 1;
        if (board[0][2] = 'X' && board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0])
            return 1;
        
        // If `computer` wins : return -1
        if (board[0][0] = 'O' && board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2])
            return -1;
        if (board[0][2] = 'O' && board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0])
            return -1;
        return 0; // No one wins
    }
```

**-1** will indicate `computer's` win.
**1** will indicate `player's` win.
**0** will indicate no winner found.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your problem is that you have "fused" your data model with your "visuals". The data structure which you use for computing the state of the game (the board) should not be tied to the way you visualize the game, i.e. it should not have spaces in the odd spots of each column.

The board needs to be a 3×3 array. Any spaces that you insert for visualizing it should be added in the `printBoard`  method. Moreover, the board does not need to be `char[][]` - you could make a special `enum` to represent an `X`, an `0`, and an unoccupied cell. Unless you plan to expand the game to larger grids, you also do not need a loop to do the diagonal.

Finally, you can eliminate most `switch` statements in your code by observing that the position 1..9 can be easily decoded into a row and a column with `/` and `%` operators, like this:

```
int row = (position-1) / 3;
int col = (position-1) % 3;
```